# Confetti animation only appearing on the lower half

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, animation

Im making a website to wish her on her birthday. its still a work in progress. ive added the confetti animation but it is only appearing on the lower half of the screen. heres the code for reference. how can i fix this? ive tried many things but nothing seems to work. Im new to stack overflow so dont know how all this works

```js
var maxParticleCount = 150; //set max confetti count
var particleSpeed = 2; //set the particle animation speed
var startConfetti; //call to start confetti animation
var stopConfetti; //call to stop adding confetti
var toggleConfetti; //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
var removeConfetti; //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately

(function() {
    startConfetti = startConfettiInner;
    stopConfetti = stopConfettiInner;
    toggleConfetti = toggleConfettiInner;
    removeConfetti = removeConfettiInner;
    var colors = ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "Pink", "SlateBlue", "LightBlue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"]
    var streamingConfetti = false;
    var animationTimer = null;
    var particles = [];
    var waveAngle = 0;
    
    function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
        particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0];
        particle.x = Math.random() * width;
        particle.y = Math.random() * height - height;
        particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
        particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
        particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
        particle.tiltAngle = 0;
        return particle;
    }

    function startConfettiInner() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) {
                    return window.setTimeout(callback, 16.6666667);
                };
        })();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
        if (canvas === null) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none");
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }, true);
        }
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        while (particles.length < maxParticleCount)
            particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
        streamingConfetti = true;
        if (animationTimer === null) {
            (function runAnimation() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                if (particles.length === 0)
                    animationTimer = null;
                else {
                    updateParticles();
                    drawParticles(context);
                    animationTimer = requestAnimFrame(runAnimation);
                }
            })();
        }
    }

    function stopConfettiInner() {
        streamingConfetti = false;
    }

    function removeConfettiInner() {
        stopConfetti();
        particles = [];
    }

    function toggleConfettiInner() {
        if (streamingConfetti)
            stopConfettiInner();
        else
            startConfettiInner();
    }

    function drawParticles(context) {
        var particle;
        var x;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            context.beginPath();
            context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
            context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
            x = particle.x + particle.tilt;
            context.moveTo(x + particle.diameter / 2, particle.y);
            context.lineTo(x, particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    function updateParticles() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var particle;
        waveAngle += 0.01;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
                particle.y = height + 100;
            else {
                particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
                particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle);
                particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + particleSpeed) * 0.5;
                particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
            }
            if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
                if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= maxParticleCount)
                    resetParticle(particle, width, height);
                else {
                    particles.splice(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <!--emoji-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <!--title-->
    <title>&#127881;Happy Birthday&#127881;</title>
    <!--animation-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <!--favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!--confetti animation-->
    <script src="confetti.js"></script>
    <!--CSS-->
<style>

</style> 
</head> 

<body style="background-color:#06589c; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
       <!-- Confetti  JS-->
    <script>

        // start

        const start = () => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                startConfetti();
            }, 1); // 1000 is time that after 1 second start the confetti ( 1000 = 1 sec)
        };

        //  Stop

        const stop = () => {
            setTimeout(function() {
                stopConfetti();
            }, 3000); // 5000 is time that after 5 second stop the confetti ( 5000 = 5 sec)
        };

        start();
        stop();
    </script>
     <div class="animated pulse infinite" style="font-size: 75px; color: white; font-family: 'Raleway'; margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 75px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Dear Eshal,</div>
     <div class="animated pulse infinite" style="font-size: 100px; color: white; font-family:'Raleway'; text-align: center; margin-top: 55px; font-weight: bold;">Happy Birthday!</div>
     <div class="Birthday Cake" style="text-align: center;">
     <img src="images/favicon.png" width="346.4px" height="310.8px" alt="Birthday Cake">
     </div>
     
 </body>
</html>
```

```js
// start
const start = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        startConfetti();
    }, 1); // 1000 is time that after 1 second start the confetti ( 1000 = 1 sec)
};

//  Stop
const stop = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        stopConfetti();
    }, 3000); // 5000 is time that after 5 second stop the confetti ( 5000 = 5 sec)
};

start();
stop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!--emoji-->
      <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
      <!--title-->
      <title>&#127881;Happy Birthday&#127881;</title>
      <!--animation-->
      <link type="text/css"   
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
      <!--favicon-->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
      <!--confetti animation-->
      <script src="confetti.js"></script>
      <!--CSS-->
      <style>
      </style> 
  </head>
  
  <body style="background-color:#06589c; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      
    <div class="animated pulse infinite"
        style="font-size: 75px;
               -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px white;
               text-shadow: 2px 2px;
               font-family: 'Raleway';
               margin-top: 30px;
               margin-left: 75px;
               margin-bottom: 10px;
               font-weight: bold;">Dear Eshal,</div>
               
     <div class="animated pulse infinite"
          style="font-size: 100px;
                 text-shadow: 3px 3px;
                 font-family:'Raleway';
                 text-align: center;
                 margin-top: 55px;
                 font-weight: bold;">Happy Birthday!</div>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Muhammed and welcome to SO. At the moment we're not able to run your code to see what is happening because you haven't included the styles and scripts. Please edit your question and create a runnable snippet (look for the `<>` icon on the question editor to create a snippet).

Comment: you should include the content of your confetti.js ... I edited the question to have runnable snippet that now throws an error because the confetti.js linked to the page and supposing to include startConfetti and stopConfetti isn't there and those functions are not defined

Comment: @DiegoDeVita for some reason i cant edit it the edit option has a (1) infront of it when i click it it just opens a window of review edits but nothing shows up

Comment: @EmielZuurbier for some reason i cant edit it the edit option has a (1) infront of it when i click it it just opens a window of review edits but nothing shows up

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @muhammad I guess it's asking you to accept my revision before you can edit your question.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita the thing is ur revision doesnt show up i open it and its just empty

Comment: To better make things clear.. the code in that snippet won't actually work because the confetti.js is still linked externally to a non existent resource. I tried to embed that code on my own html file including the confetti.js part defined separately. The problem is much more than what you stated in your question. You have two undeclared variables `particleSpeed` and `maxParticleCount` that will just break the execution. You should declare those at some point in the functions where they get used. After then it will work.. I tried it.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita idk anything abt those 2 variables i just copied the code from confetti.js and attached it here

Comment: I added them in my answer showing you the working snippet. I said those declarations should be in the confetti.js but actually you are free to declare them anywhere you like as var instead of using let. `var nameofvariable;` declares the variable in the global scope so it will be visible from any other scope. By the way the snippet works. Please check it out and tell your opinion if it matches the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

The code in that snippet won't actually work because the `confetti.js` is still linked externally to a non existent resource.

I tried to embed that code on my own html file including the `confetti.js` part defined separately.

The problem is different than what you stated in your question. You have two undeclared variables `particleSpeed` and `maxParticleCount` that will just break the execution.

Here's that same snippet with those variables declared and initialized in the global scope.

If you run the snippet it will show the animation showing up just under the happy birthday message and lasting the amount of time you defined through start/stop.

```js
(function() {
    startConfetti = startConfettiInner;
    stopConfetti = stopConfettiInner;
    toggleConfetti = toggleConfettiInner;
    removeConfetti = removeConfettiInner;
    var colors = ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "Pink", "SlateBlue", "LightBlue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"]
    var streamingConfetti = false;
    var animationTimer = null;
    var particles = [];
    var waveAngle = 0;

    function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
        particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0];
        particle.x = Math.random() * width;
        particle.y = Math.random() * height - height;
        particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
        particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
        particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
        particle.tiltAngle = 0;
        return particle;
    }

    function startConfettiInner() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (callback) {
                    return window.setTimeout(callback, 16.6666667);
                };
        })();
        var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
        if (canvas === null) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
            canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none");
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            }, true);
        }
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        while (particles.length < maxParticleCount)
            particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
        streamingConfetti = true;
        if (animationTimer === null) {
            (function runAnimation() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                if (particles.length === 0)
                    animationTimer = null;
                else {
                    updateParticles();
                    drawParticles(context);
                    animationTimer = requestAnimFrame(runAnimation);
                }
            })();
        }
    }

    function stopConfettiInner() {
        streamingConfetti = false;
    }

    function removeConfettiInner() {
        stopConfetti();
        particles = [];
    }

    function toggleConfettiInner() {
        if (streamingConfetti)
            stopConfettiInner();
        else
            startConfettiInner();
    }

    function drawParticles(context) {
        var particle;
        var x;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            context.beginPath();
            context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
            context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
            x = particle.x + particle.tilt;
            context.moveTo(x + particle.diameter / 2, particle.y);
            context.lineTo(x, particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2);
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    function updateParticles() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        var particle;
        waveAngle += 0.01;
        for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
            particle = particles[i];
            if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
                particle.y = height + 100;
            else {
                particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
                particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle);
                particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + particleSpeed) * 0.5;
                particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
            }
            if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
                if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= maxParticleCount)
                    resetParticle(particle, width, height);
                else {
                    particles.splice(i, 1);
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
})();

/*these declarations were missing*/
var maxParticleCount = 100;
var particleSpeed = 1;

// start
const start = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        startConfetti();
    }, 1); // 1000 is time that after 1 second start the confetti ( 1000 = 1 sec)
};

//  Stop
const stop = () => {
    setTimeout(function() {
        stopConfetti();
    }, 3000); // 5000 is time that after 5 second stop the confetti ( 5000 = 5 sec)
};

start();
stop();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <!--emoji-->
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <!--title-->
      <title>&#127881;Happy Birthday&#127881;</title>
      <!--animation-->
      <link type="text/css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
      <!--favicon-->
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet'>
      <!--confetti animation-->
      <!-- <script src="confetti.js"></script> -->
      <!--CSS-->
      <style>
      </style>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#06589c; width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <div class="animated pulse infinite"
        style="font-size: 75px;
               -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px white;
               text-shadow: 2px 2px;
               font-family: 'Raleway';
               margin-top: 30px;
               margin-left: 75px;
               margin-bottom: 10px;
               font-weight: bold;">Dear Eshal,</div>

     <div class="animated pulse infinite"
          style="font-size: 100px;
                 text-shadow: 3px 3px;
                 font-family:'Raleway';
                 text-align: center;
                 margin-top: 55px;
                 font-weight: bold;">Happy Birthday!</div>

   </body>
</html>
```